# RSpec: paranoid2 - can't modify frozen Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, acts-as-paranoid

I'm working on RSpec tests for my model which uses [paranoid2 gem](https://github.com/anjlab/paranoid2). This is some kind of paranoia or acts_as_paranoid - overwrites .delete and .destroy and some other with it's own versions which marks data as deleted rather than deleting it until you force it to with `(forced: true)` parameter.

**My app works just fine and I have problems only with the rspec.**

spec/models/slide_spec.rb:

```
describe Slide do

 let (:slide) { build(:slide) }

  describe "after .destroy(force: true)" do
   before do      
      slide.save
      slide.destroy(force: false)      
   end
    it "is invisible" do
      expect{slide.destroy(force: true)}.to_not change(Slide, :count)
    end
    it "visible if .only_deleted" do
      expect{slide.destroy(force: true)}.to change(Slide.only_deleted, :count).by(-1)
    end    
    it "visible if .with_deleted" do
      expect{slide.destroy(force: true)}.to change(Slide.with_deleted, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end
 end
```

rspec output:

```
  after .destroy(force: true)
    visible if .with_deleted (FAILED - 1)
    visible if .only_deleted (FAILED - 2)
    is invisible (FAILED - 3)

Failures:

  1) Slide after .destroy(force: true) visible if .with_deleted
     Failure/Error: expect{slide.destroy(force: true)}.to change(Slide.with_deleted, :count).by(-1)
     RuntimeError:
       can't modify frozen Hash
     # ./spec/models/slide_spec.rb:52:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/slide_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) same as above

  3) same sa above
```

/app/model/slide.rb:

```
class Slide < ActiveRecord::Base
    paranoid
    ...
```

Comment: You're using `build` instead of `create`, so instance is not saved to DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because Rails marks the internal attributes hash with `freeze` after calling destroy on a model. This frozen hash prohibits the object from further change: A later `destroy(force: true)` wants to remove the `id`, a `reload` wants to override some attributes with fresh value from the database - both will fail.

The only way to avoid this problem is to reload the object manually:

```
describe "after .destroy(force: true)" do
  before do
    slide.save
    slide.destroy(force: false)
    @slide = Slide.with_deleted.find(slide.id)  # manual reload
  end
  it "is invisible" do
    expect{@slide.destroy(force: true)}.to_not change(Slide, :count)
  end
  it "visible if .only_deleted" do
    expect{@slide.destroy(force: true)}.to change(Slide.only_deleted, :count).by(-1)
  end
  it "visible if .with_deleted" do
    expect{@slide.destroy(force: true)}.to change(Slide.with_deleted, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: doesn't work. app is available at [github](https://github.com/pawel7318/footoo.git)

Comment: @pawel7318: Thanks for sharing the code, made it much easier to play around with the problem. I updated my answer, should work now.